# Tab visibility after managed package upgrade

Tags: managed-package, tab, release

I have a managed release package at version v1. I added a new tab in version v2 and upgraded the package. After installation of this upgraded package, the new tab is not visible for the app.  I checked my custom app and see that the new tab is not included in the list of included-tabs. However, when I created the upgrade package, I had added it to the App.

To make the tab visible, I had to manually include the tab in the test-org.

Does this mean if I add a new tab during upgrade, all the subscribers would have to manually include the tab in their respective orgs?
Is this the desired behavior? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications are now upgradeable as part of a package upgrade. It is always important that you check the documentation to ensure that you have the most recent information on packaging behavior before making any assumptions.

---

## Original Answer

That's correct. System administrators can customize the app after installation, so the system will not upgrade the app because it may override any customizations the system administrators may have made. There are a few elements like that, such as page layouts, list views, and email templates. See [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) for a full list of objects. The first column next to the component type will say "Yes" if the component is updated during upgrades, or "No" if not.

Comment: @sfdcfox but Application says Yes in the first column, am I looking at the wrong listing?

Comment: @PhilB This answer was correct at the time. See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002164121/https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm).

Comment: @PhilB Also, you might want to check/test this to be sure. There have been a number of ... interesting documentation bugs recently.

Comment: @sfdcfox the functionality appears to be the same, adding a tab to the packaged app does not come through in upgrades, curious that the documentation does not reflect that anymore.

Comment: @PhilB So... another documentation bug, maybe? Perhaps someone needs to open a case with support?